# How to use variables from input data file(json file) for a postman collection while running using newman

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I have a input data sheet in json format I want to pick the values name and passsword from this sheet and pass it in the request body of a postman request using pre-request script. This is the input sheet :

```
[
  {
    "num_of_steps": "1",
    "testcases": [
      {
        "comment": "Login",
        "test case": "1",
        "data": {
          "version": "2.1"
        },
        "Input": {
          "name": "panda",
          "password": "apple123"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So What will be the statement/expression in postman to pick name and password that is to be written in the pre-requuest script, I have tried  `pm.iterationData.get("name");` but this works only when the values are directly present in the inputsheet without any branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Newman command options` in [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/using-newman-cli/newman-options/)

```
-d, --iteration-data [file] : Specify a data file to use, either JSON or CSV.
```

##### #1 Save as `data.json`

this data, I suppose your data is this object of array format.

```json
[
    {
        "num_of_steps": "1",
        "testcases": [
          {
            "comment": "Login",
            "test case": "1",
            "data": {
              "version": "2.1"
            },
            "Input": {
              "name": "panda",
              "password": "apple123"
            }
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "num_of_steps": "2",
        "testcases": [
          {
            "comment": "Login",
            "test case": "1",
            "data": {
              "version": "2.1"
            },
            "Input": {
              "name": "monkey",
              "password": "strong_password1234"
            }
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

##### #2 Set global variable

To assign in `Pre-request Script` tab of Postman

```
pm.globals.set("jsonBody", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.toObject()));
var jsonData = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("jsonBody"))
var input = jsonData["testcases"][0]["Input"];
pm.globals.set("username", input?.name);
pm.globals.set("password", input?.password);
```

Will set Global Variable the `username` and `password` after POST call.

[image]

##### #3 Access variable in input body

In input Body of POST call

```
{
    "username": "{{username}}",
    "password": "{{password}}"
}
```

[image]

##### #4 Setup test in `Tests` tab of Postman

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

var username = jsonData["username"]
var password = jsonData["password"]

pm.test('Check username = ' + JSON.stringify(username), function () {
    pm.expect(username).to.equal(pm.globals.get("username"));
});

pm.test('Check password = ' + JSON.stringify(password), function () {
    pm.expect(password).to.equal(pm.globals.get("password"));
});
```

[image]

##### #5 Export collection

[image]

[image]

##### #6 Demo server by Flask of Python

It will play-back from POST of input body to output body

Save as the `server.py` filename.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/user", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        json = request.get_json()
        return json, 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

##### #7 Install flask and run server

```
pip install flask
```

```
python server.py
```

[image]

##### #8 Run `newman` with `data.json` and the collection file.

```
newman run ./demo.postman_collection.json  --iteration-data ./data.json
```

You can see the user and password back to output body.
Those values come from your JSON object array file.

Result Testing

[image]

Comment: Actually I can't convert into single json and provide it in the pre request script, I need to used a external json file as a input data sheet so whenever there's a changes change I could just edit the input sheet instead of the postman collection. So is there a way/expression so that I could pick the variables from the external json sheet. Thank you!

Comment: @sleepingpanda, OK, I update my answer with `--iteration-data` for accessing JSON file.

Comment: Sorry, One more doubt I only need to pick the username and password from that input json sheet to pass in the request body, so what will be the code in pre request script to only pick username and password from json file

Comment: OK, I updated again only use the `username` and `password`.