# How can I see these specific response headers?

Tags: postman, http-headers, httpresponse, twitch-api

I am using Twitch's API to gather data for a web app I'm developing.

Per the documentation,

[image: I should be able to view these in the header response]

However, when I make the request in Postman, I don't see it.

[image: Not here.]

They are in the header response section (I didn't screenshot the remaining half of the responses).

Am I looking in the wrong place?

I've looked in the Headers Response section of the API request I made. Additionally, I looked in the Headers Requests section in the console too.

Answer (score 0):

The Headers Tab in Postman is request(input) headers not the response(output) headers data.
It is located in the output area.
[image]

You can see (or assign) the response headers at `Test` tab.

Also `curl` 's -v option can see the headers from tesminal.

```curl
curl --location 'http://localhost:5000/user' \
-v \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
    "username": "username",
    "password": "1234"
}'
```

Result
[image]

You can see or assign to variable at `Test` Tab's by script

```js
headers = pm.response.headers.all();
jsonHeader = JSON.stringify(headers);
console.log(jsonHeader)

headers.forEach(function(header){
    if(header.key == "Ratelimit-Reset"){
        pm.globals.set("Ratelimit-Reset", header.value)
        console.log(header.value)
        return;
    }    
})
```

[image]

you can assign global variable for specific key/value

[image]

Demo Server (emulate your Twitch's API server) by Python Flask.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/user", methods=["POST"])
def post_test():
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (content_type == 'application/json'):
        resp = Response(request.get_json())
        resp.headers['x-amzn-Requestid'] = '20122de8-3fd9-4439-b7f8-5c76a9dcf77e'
        resp.headers['x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length'] = '6dd53770-ffa0-4f5f-95e6-b2fabe98c483'
        resp.headers['x-amz-apigw-id'] = 'e2994bb8-22c2-4ac5-b936-b541ac1bf99b'
        resp.headers['x-amzn-Rmapped-Date'] = '2023-08-17 16:45:43 UTC'
        resp.headers['x-Count'] = '1234'
        resp.headers['Ratelimit-Limit'] = '150'
        resp.headers['Ratelimit-Remaining'] = '98'
        resp.headers['Ratelimit-Reset'] = '1692306166'
        return resp, 201
    else:
        return 'Content-Type not supported!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76859919/how-to-use-variables-from-input-data-filejson-file-for-a-postman-collection-wh/76861876#76861876) for install dependency and run it.

Comment: I am still not seeing them.

[This image shows my Header Responses](https://i.ibb.co/Ltq1N6N/Screenshot-2023-08-17-at-10-52-04-AM.png)

Comment: That mean you server not added that key/values. Can you try my emulate server by Flaks? It will see the three values.

Comment: No worries, I was actually able to rectify my issues. No more help is needed!